# How do I configure IIS to send JSP requests to Tomcat?

Tags: iis, tomcat

I have a web application written mainly in JSP and servlet. I use Tomcat 7.0.26 as my application server. I want this application to run via IIS, though I can run it using Tomcat.

By searching the Web, I learned that I have to map `index.jsp` to the IIS script directory in such a way that when the IIS server receives a JSP request, it forwards that request to the Tomcat server.

How do I configure this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Check this howto:
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Comment: can you please tell me that where to download that isapi_redirect.dll file or how to build it. This is the 2nd day, I am not been able to find that dll file for my win-xp OS.

Comment: http://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/windows/